# Taylor polynomial related series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

Given $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ an analytical function, $$ (T_nf)(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k} $$ and $$ (R_nf)(x) = f(x) -(T_nf)(x), $$ calculate the sum of the following series: $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(R_nf)(t)x^n}$$ where $t, x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Someting must be wrong here. The definitions of $T_nf$ and $R_nf$ do not depend on $n$. Also, what kind of answer are you looking for? More importantly, you forgot to show your own efforts.

Comment: My bad, I edited the question, should be fine now. I don't know how to start this problem

Comment: "I don't know how to start this." is very rarely justified, and also, people on this site usually don't feel motivated answering posts where the author does not show his or her personal efforts. E.g., did you try some concrete functions? For example, polynomials, $e^x$, etc.? If you do, you might obtain a conjecture. It still might be false, but it is a start.

Comment: I tried assigning $ x = 1 $ and using the functions $ e^x $ and $ sin x $, thus transforming the power series into a numerical series, but this is where I stopped.

Comment: Are you sure there is no restriction on $x$ for the last series? E.g., $|x|<1$?

Comment: Pretty sure, but I think you may need to put the restrictions yourself in order to get to the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, this is a clear case of a technique known as *"let's just unroll the definitions and see where that leads us, shall we?"*

- For $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x\neq 1$, letting $a_k \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$ for all $k\geq 0$, 
  $$
  \begin{align}
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty (R_n f)(t) x^n
  &= 
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=n+1}^\infty a_m t^m x^n
  =
  \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_m t^m x^n
  =
  \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m t^m  \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} x^n \\
  &=
  \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m t^m  \frac{1-x^{m}}{1-x}
  = \frac{1}{1-x} \left( 
  \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m t^m - \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m (xt)^m \right)\\
  &= \frac{f(t) - f(xt)}{1-x} 
  \end{align}$$

For $x=0$: we do get $R_0 f(t) = f(t)-f(0)$, so this passes a simple sanity check.

- For $x=1$, you want to compute $\sum_{m=0}^\infty m a_m t^m  = t \sum_{m=1}^\infty m a_m t^{m-1} = t f'(t)$.